# Race condition with versioning

Tags: postgresql, race-condition

In my application using Postgresql, the ordering product process can potentially lead to race conditions. Let me describe my case. I have three tables in the database:

- The first one is Product table:

```
Id string
Quantity int
```

- User

```
Id string
Name string
```

- Ordering

```
Id string
UserId string
ProductId string
Quantity int
```

In this process, I have two stages to complete it. I read from Product table to check *"Is the product available"* if the room is not available I would respond with an error message to user; on the other hand, I would create a record for Ordering table, and a response success message to user.

This is sql to handle that:

```
--- get quantity from product id
SELECT quantity
FROM Product
WHERE id = '456';

--- if the product's quantity is greater than the ordering quantity then
UPDATE Product
SET quantity = quantity - 1
WHERE id = '456';

INSERT INTO Ordering (id, user_id, product_id, quantity)
VALUES ('1', '123', '456', 1);

--- else I would respond to customer error response
```

However I realized that this process can potentially lead to race conditions. Then I found an idea to solve it. I created a field named **version** to Product and Ordering table. And I update version when checking available products. But I have a problem with this solution.

The SQL will become as below:

```
--- get quantity from product id
SELECT quantity
FROM Product
WHERE id = '456' and version = 1;

--- if the product's quantity is greater than the ordering quantity then
UPDATE Product
SET quantity = quantity - 1, version = version + 1
WHERE id = '456' and version = 1;

INSERT INTO Ordering (id, user_id, product_id, quantity, version)
VALUES ('1', '123', '456', 1, 1);

--- else I would respond to the customer error response
```

If the product's quantity is 99. And I have 100 requests to buy products from customers at the same time. In this situation, only one customer ordered successfully and the other one failed. But I expected that 99 people would order successfully and only one customer failed.

Can someone give me some suggestions about this problem? It takes me a long time to make a consideration. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build your own [mvcc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)? Don't do that, instead solve the problem with proper transaction handling and `SELECT FOR UPDATE`

Comment: Yeah, I know that statement, but I don't want to lock that row, because I have some functions which must read data from this row.

Comment: Locking does not prevent reading data

Comment: OK I have a situation. Two requests read data from Product table at the same time. Currently, there is one product in the store. In the BE code, two requests have a quantity valued at 1. The first one updates the Product table and commits it. Then the second one also dates the Product table and commits it. Because the quantity variable in the BE was 1.

Comment: No, the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` waits for the previous transaction to finish, the transaction that came second would read `0` already. You could also use `SELECT` (without `FOR UPDATE`) to read without waiting, but then you should do the `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE quantity = 1` (i.e. the value that you just read) so that it would fail when it had been updated in the mean time.

Comment: In this particular example, you don't even need the separate `SELECT` (`FOR UPDATE`), you could just do it in a single atomic `UPDATE product SET quantity = quanity - 1 WHERE id = '456' AND quantity >= 1 RETURNING quantity`. You'd get back either 1 or 0 rows.

Comment: oh, SELECT FOR UPDATE just block another SELECT FOR UPDATE with the same row. I have a confusion about this statement. I think it is one answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Do not test for available quantity, instead let the database automatically check it. Put a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) specifying the resulting quantity must not be less that 0.

```
alter table products
      add constraint positive_quantity check (quantity >= 0);
```

Now when you update the quantity Postgres will ensure the resulting quantity is 0 or greater (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ctZEQVVR)). If it is then the update is performed and the row is locked from further updates (it can still be read, and gets the value prior updated) until committed. Subsequent updates will perform the same check starting with the updated value. If the resulting quantity is less than 0 an exception. You need to process the exception and not issue the insert.  
NOTE: Just make sure the `products` table update and the `orders` table insert are in the same transaction.

Comment: This is a solution for race conditions. But I expect an answer about my way using `version`.